# For-loop multi-threading passes upper bound

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, begininvoke

We are learning multi-threadding today in class and we came across a very curious error. When doing a for loop in our new thread the upper bound of the for loop keeps getting passed. The thread is being killed but then another value will appear and end another thread.

For the purpose of debugging the error I changed the upper bound to 90 to avoid the OutOfRange Exception on the progressbar.

While outputting the counter to the progressing bar and updating the progress bar I got this in my output window.

[image: while updating progress bar]

If i commented out the updating on the progress bar (`pbLoad.Value = i;`) I got this in my output window

[image: while not updating the progress bar]

I have tried changing the loop to `i<101` and also tried moving where the `i++` was but it made no difference

EDIT: This is coming from the `BeginInvoke`. When i switched it to `Invoke` it worked but then I will get a deadlock when trying to use the cancel button.

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread backgroundThread;
        bool stopExecution = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopExecution = false;
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            backgroundThread = new Thread(DoDomethingThatTakesAWhile);
            backgroundThread.Start();
        }

        private void DoDomethingThatTakesAWhile()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                if (!stopExecution)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                    if (pbLoad.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        MethodInvoker myMethod
                            = new MethodInvoker(
                                delegate
                                {
                                    if (!stopExecution)
                                    {
                                        pbLoad.Value = i;
                                        Debug.WriteLine(i); //i to output window                                        
                                    }
                                });
                        pbLoad.BeginInvoke(myMethod);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pbLoad.Value = i;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //backgroundThread.Abort();
            stopExecution = true;
            backgroundThread.Join();

            pbLoad.Value = 0;
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sounds like a race condition, a thread is incrementing the value before the loop can completely end processing.

Comment: The value is only being modified and accessed in that one thread though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `MethodInvoke` it will not occurs at that moment, but *some time* later.

In your scenario you have a chance of following to occurs:

- invoked code is finally executed;
- the loop is already finished (and `i` become 101)
- you are accessing `i` directly and you read 101.

And to fix it you can make a copy of `i` (by passing it as a parameter to invoked method):

```
pbLoad.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(a =>
{
    if (!stopExecution)
    {
        pbLoad.Value = a;
        Debug.WriteLine(a); //a to output window                                        
    }
}), new object[] { i });
```

P.S: you don't need to check for `InvokeRequired`, unless you plan to call `DoDomethingThatTakesAWhile` method directly, which I assume is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `BeginInvoke` which explicitly opens the possibility for races. I recommend synchronous invoking.

Furthermore, you are capturing `i`, not its value. This is racy and only works by accident because you're sleeping.

Either of the changes will fix the problem. Do both of them.

If you can, abolish this low-level use of synchronization and use async/await.

Comment: I am quite sure `Task` is the way to go today (not async/await). But I am sad everybody say `wpf` in `winforms` topics and `taks` in `thread`  topics. I cry then.

Comment: @Sinatr `await` is the mechanism used to resume after a Task has complete. The two are complementary techniques. You can still use thread-backed Tasks which is still useful.